# F# type confusion - I'm sure I'm getting the value I need but the compiler, at run time, does not agree

Tags: types, f#, functional-programming, type-providers

I've got a nice QC testing tool that I access via VB from an existing setup. This tool give me strong typed access to the tables without making new classes etc. However one of the tables, sadly, uses a commalist instead of child tables.

This commalist is causing me issues. The code below, in theory, should split the row.commalist and then tell me if a given number lies within.

I was able to output the value from the CommaListValues bit - it's bool. I feed it the parameters as given and the compiler seems happy.

Why won't it, at run time, use the boolean as criteria? I've got a mental block I guess - I don't use F# routinely but I'm very much wanting to - unfortunately these niggles eat the time.

Can anyone help?

Edited as requested. The typical values for the commalist sample would be:"234,132,554,6344,243,677"

```
module quality_control

open System
open System.Collections.Generic
open System.Data
open System.Data.Linq
open Microsoft.FSharp.Data.TypeProviders
open Microsoft.FSharp.Linq

type dbschema = SqlDataConnection<"Data Source=SomeServer;Initial Catalog=SQLDB;User ID=sa;Password=######">

let db = dbschema.GetDataContext()

type QualityChecks(SingleIDToMatch) =
  let questionList ( q : string, SingleIDToMatch: string) = q.Split [| ','|] |> fun x -> x.Equals(SingleIDToMatch) 

  member x.MatchID=
      query{
       for row in db.SomeTableWithCommaListColumn do
       where (questionList(row.CommaListValue, System.Convert.ToString(SingleIDToMatch)))
       select row}
```

I get the following error:

System.ArgumentException occurred
  HResult=-2147024809
  Message=The argument 'value' was the wrong type. Expected 'System.Func`2[System.Tuple`2[System.String,System.String],System.Boolean]'. Actual 'System.Boolean'.
  Source=System.Data.Linq
  StackTrace:
       at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlMethodCall.set_Object(SqlExpression value)
       at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlMethodCall..ctor(Type clrType, ProviderType sqlType, MethodInfo method, SqlExpression obj, IEnumerable`1 args, Expression sourceExpression)
       at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlFactory.MethodCall(MethodInfo method, SqlExpression obj, SqlExpression[] args, Expression sourceExpression)
       at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression mc)
       at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitInner(Expression node)
       at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitExpression(Expression exp)
       at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitWhere(Expression sequence, LambdaExpression predicate)
       at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitSequenceOperatorCall(MethodCallExpression mc)
       at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression mc)
       at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitInner(Expression node)
       at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.ConvertOuter(Expression node)
       at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.BuildQuery(Expression query, SqlNodeAnnotations annotations)
       at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.System.Data.Linq.Provider.IProvider.Execute(Expression query)
       at System.Data.Linq.DataQuery`1.System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
       at REMOVED PROJECT DETAILS
  InnerException:

Comment: On what line number is this error occurring?

Comment: Also, could you give us a sample of the `CommaListValue` column?

Comment: Can you post your code for function questionList ?

Comment: @Wei Ma the error happens in a VB application when attempting to use call QualityCheck.MatchID(AnyValue). I think I know why now though - though I've yet to test it.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think it's simply that I'm asking for a single Boolean but the questionList is actually a sequence of returned Booleans. So I've got to aggregate the answer to come up with True if even one is matched.

Comment: If that's the case, your F# code should not compile. Because the where function expects a t->boolean, not a t->boolean list.

Comment: When running a `query` against the DB, you should only use constructs that can be converted to SQL.  Since `questionList` is a local function, it can't be translated, and I'm not surprised that it doesn't work (though the actual error is a bit weird...).

Comment: @kvb My thought process was grab the values from the row provided by the type provider, put that straight into the local function and work on the result. But have I got that backwards? The type provider doesn't have any such value but works backwards to produce the sql-after the fact?

Comment: I'll look again. It does sound right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The type provider attempts to convert the query expression into SQL, but it isn't able to translate the `questionList()` call into a `WHERE` clause. The simple solution is to change `MatchID()` to look like this:

```
member x.MatchID=
    let idString = singleIDToMatch.ToString()
    query {
        for row in db.SomeTableWithCommaListColumn do
        where (row.CommaListValue.EndsWith("," + idString)
            || row.CommaListValue.StartsWith(idString + ",")
            || row.CommaListValue.Contains("," + idString + ","))
        select row }
```

This executes the following SQL:

```
SELECT [t0].[CommaListValue]
FROM   [dbo].[SomeTableWithCommaListColumn] AS [t0]
WHERE  ([t0].[CommaListValue] LIKE @p0)
       OR ([t0].[CommaListValue] LIKE @p1)
       OR ([t0].[CommaListValue] LIKE @p2)
```

(the parameters include the appropriate wildcards to give results equivalent to the F# code in the query expression)

---

### Composition

If you need to compose multiple `WHERE` clauses, you can chain query expressions, like this:

```
let withAtLeast10Characters (q : Linq.IQueryable<dbschema.ServiceTypes.SomeTableWithCommaListColumn>) =
    query {
        for row in q do
        where (row.CommaListValue.Length >= 10)
        select row }

let result = qualityChecks.MatchID |> withAtLeast10Characters
```

When this is evaluated, you'll get SQL that looks like this:

```
SELECT [t0].[CommaListValue]
FROM   [dbo].[SomeTableWithCommaListColumn] AS [t0]
WHERE  (DATALENGTH([t0].[CommaListValue]) >= @p0)
       AND (([t0].[CommaListValue] LIKE @p1)
            OR ([t0].[CommaListValue] LIKE @p2)
            OR ([t0].[CommaListValue] LIKE @p3))
```

Comment: Thank you! Its been a while since I looked at this.